# What type of 360 format is this?

Tags: premiere, 360video

I want to download this video and view it in Premiere Pro:

After downloading and scrubbing through the video, it appears to be two (seemingly identical) scenes stacked on top of each other.

This seems to be very different from the equirectangular footage I output with my GoPro Max after converting from .360, for instance.

### Question

How do I get  360 videos from YouTube into equirectangular format and view them in Premiere like on most GoPro Max workflows?

Namely, I want to change the tilt and zoom to create the “tiny planet” effect. I can make that effect easily with equirectangular videos, but when I tried with the above video, it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youtube 360 videos are in EAC, equi-angular cubemap format. FFmpeg have filter named v360 that can convert such videos to equirectangular or stereographic (also known as tiny planet) format (among many others) by using CPU.

Comment: im trying to implement, but ffmpeg is a bit over my head. would you mind converting the video to equirectangular and posting somewhere?

Comment: What resolution/quality from original youtube video you need? I can encode to lossless h264 if that is supported by your software?

Comment: thats great! my application is not resolution intensive, something in the 480 to 720 range would be perfect, and yeah, lossless h264 is a good format for me

Comment: Here it is, video only: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O-lEzGIZX_A_0npCIpfGqEla903qCU8C